# How do I add a link inside <li> keeping li and li hover?

Tags: html, css

When I add a link like this:

`<li><a href="link"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>`

it adds a link, but it automatically displays an icon in violet color... so it doesn't even display neither `li` nor `li:hover`
I want to have a link (`<a href>`) inside the `li` and still make `li` and `li:hover` work.

I have this in my html. Icons are from `fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css` (external site css link)

First Icon here is with the link, Second one `li:hover`, 3rd one - `li`

[image]

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 20%;
  transition: .5s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

li:hover {
  color: #cf0c57;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0-beta1/css/all.css">

<nav class="container-social item">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. I had to use `https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0-beta1/css/all.css` to get the icons to show

Comment: It is not clear what you want, but there are no links in your HTML

Comment: Hi RizzyD, try `li>a { background: unset; text-decoration: unset; color: unset; }`.

Comment: Why not `li a { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) }` and `li:hover a { color: #cf0c57; }`?